# How to pass a parameter to purrr's map function without using formula notation?

Tags: r, function, dictionary, formula, purrr

I am following along Hadley Wickham's online book "R for Data Science" and got a little confused once the purrr:map function was introduced. In particular, [question 21.5.3 (4)](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#exercises-58) asks to create 10 random normals for each of the means (-10, 0, 10, 100) but my attempts to apply a function using map failed.

I did note that (unlike previous examples) the mean serves as a parameter here and not as the object to which the function is applied. The [solution](https://jrnold.github.io/r4ds-exercise-solutions/iteration.html#the-map-functions) makes use of the (abbreviated) formula notation. What exactly lets the code work with a formula rather than a function even though the [explanation](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#shortcuts) suggests that both are equivalent inside map()?

The given solution is:

```r
library("tidyverse")

mu <- c(-10, 0, 10, 100)
map(mu, ~ rnorm(n = 10, mean = .))
```

To me, the equivalent function would look something like:

```r
library("tidyverse")

mu <- c(-10, 0, 10, 100)
map(mu, rnorm(n = 10, mean = mu))
```

Note also that it is indeed possible to use the vector that is passed to map as a parameter to a function, as in:

```r
library("tidyverse")

map(1:5, rnorm)
```

Comment: The first one would be the correct version.  In the second, you are passing multiple elements to `mean` which takes only a single value

Comment: `rnorm` is vectorized. You do not want to use `map` again. just do `matrix(rnorm(100,mu),10)`. This will give you what you want

Answer (score 0):

```r
mu <- c(-10, 0, 10, 100)
#map(mu, rnorm(n = 10, mean = mu)) 
map(mu, partial(rnorm, n = 10)) 
map(mu, rnorm, n = 10) 
map(mu, function(x, n = 10) rnorm(n = n, mean = x))
```

Three different ways of doing it. Personally, I like number 2.